# Qt Whats This using a link/anchor

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

How can I put an anchor `<a>` into a `whatsThis` for a widget an intercept it being clicked?

I know about `linkActivated` in a QLabel, or `linkClicked` in a QTextBrowser, but I don't know how I can do the same thing with a Whats This text.

To be clear, I want to know if this is possible without interception help events and managing the WhatsThis mechanism on my own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question, it's that you want to know if there is a `SIGNAL()` for this. There does not appear to be. Seems you have to watch for the `QWhatsThisClickedEvent` by deriving your own Widget class or with some kind of global filter:

http://qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-7394.html

FYI, the actual point where the `QWhatsThisClickedEvent` is emitted in the Qt sources is here:

http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/gui/kernel/qwhatsthis.cpp#line264

Comment: I took this approach. I already have a custom "notify" function in my application class so I just watched for the `QWhatsThisClickedEvent`.  I just pass the Url to `QDesktopServices::openUrl` and let the normal mechanism take over (for which I already have a hook). Strange this isn't the default behaviour.

Comment: Does seem strange, but having a default behavior that lets a potential text injection start another application on the system might be considered a security risk of some sort...?  Then again, I might be reading too much into it.  :)

Answer (score 3):

HostileFork's answer is pretty much on the money. One simple approach that may work unless you have widgets which catch `WhatsThisClicked` events themselves is to listen for `WhatsThisClicked` events in your main window's widget. The code is pretty simple, something like the following:

```
bool  MyMainWindow::event(QEvent* ev)
{
    if (ev->type() == QEvent::WhatsThisClicked)
    {
        ev->accept();
        QWhatsThisClickedEvent* whatsThisEvent = dynamic_cast<QWhatsThisClickedEvent*>(ev);
        assert(whatsThisEvent);
        QDesktopServices::openUrl(whatsThisEvent->href());
        return true;
    }
    return QMainWindow::event(ev);
}
```